# parent div expanding to child div

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have to divs:

```
<div id="outerContent">
  <div id="innerContent">
  </div>
</div>
```

innerContents' position is absolute (I need it that way for JavaScript animation). How do I get outerContent to expand to innerContents' height as if innerContent wouldn't be set to position:absolute?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use `position: relative`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) You should be able to slide the innerdiv away without the need of `position:absolute;`, `position:relative;` should suffice. The advantage is it's still considered to be in the rendering flow, as aveic called it.

See [my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JakobTischler/zRhPN/6/)

2) if you do want to use `absolute`, you can make sure it doesn't screw anything up by only enabling it with JS, since you're using JS anyway to perform the animation. So in JS, just say `$('#innerDiv').css({position: absolute});` and you still won't abandon people without JS enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Setting position:absolute removes the rendering of element from the document's rendering flow. So parent element does know nothing about the inner element.

You can use javascript to sync their widths.
Like that:

```
$('#outerContent').width($('#innerContent').width());
```

And same with height.

And there is other option.

```
<div id="outerContent">
  <div id="innerContent"></div>
  <div id="innerContentDouble" style="visibility:hidden"></div>
</div>
```

The innerContentDouble should have the same content as innerContent, but it shouldn't be position:absolute. So the parent's div will expand, but coz of "visibility:hidden" the contents of "doubled" div won't be displayed. But it's not a really good practice :)

Comment: +1. Note that the second method is far from perfect, as the "duplicate" div may be a different size when it's placed in the "normal" position of the document's flow compared to when it's positioned absolutely.

Comment: the javascript wouldn't work for me, because I want the site to degrade beautifully if javascript is turned off. I wouldn't want to use the second method - as you said: it's not really good practice. What I'm actually trying to achieve is to animate the div to slide left off the screen and then after jQuery puts some new content in, slide in from the right side of the screen again. From what I've read - it can only be achieved if the div is positioned absolutely. Any other ideas?